# Test cases in a separate file for templated test cases

Tags: robotframework

Can it be possible that I have test cases in a separate file ??
The reason for this being that the templated test cases being dynamic which are created as part of the suite setup process.
Just for elaboration here is the design in mind ->
The list of test case templates need to be created as part of the suite setup.
Subsequently they are referenced as part of the testing process.
Can this be done using robotframework?
I have a script that can generate the templated test cases.

Answer (score 0):

As I have researched about this topic I have come to know that there is no way present as of such and such a design is not possible presently. Although I have raised this issue with the developers.